# BeanIO - override custom parser for multi character delimiter i.e. ~^~

Tags: java

I have written class to override default parsor for delimiter but it is not working. Appriciate your help.

```
public class CMRDelimitedRecordParserFactory extends DelimitedRecordParserFactory implements  RecordParserFactory {

private static final Logger logger = Logger
        .getLogger(CMRDelimitedRecordParserFactory.class);
@Override
public RecordWriter createWriter(Writer out) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    logger.debug("Inside CMR DelimitedRecordParserFactory...");
    System.out.println("Inside CMR DelimitedRecordParserFactory...");
    if (!(out instanceof BufferedWriter)) {
        out = new BufferedWriter(out);
    }

    final BufferedWriter writer = (BufferedWriter) out;

    return new CMRRecordWriter(writer, this);
}
}

public class CMRRecordWriter extends DelimitedWriter {

private static final Logger logger = Logger
        .getLogger(CMRRecordWriter.class);
private char escapeChar = '\\';
private boolean escapeEnabled = true;
private String recordTerminator;                
private Writer out;

//boolean escapeEnabled;
char delim = '~';
String cmrdelimitor;
String cmrAppender = "~^";

public CMRRecordWriter(Writer out) {
    this(out, '\t');
}

public CMRRecordWriter(Writer out, char delimiter) {
    this(out, new DelimitedParserConfiguration(delimiter));
}

public CMRRecordWriter(Writer out, DelimitedParserConfiguration config) {
    super(out, config);
    this.out = out;
    delim = config.getDelimiter();

    logger.debug("&&&& Config Delimiter is : " + delim);

    System.out.println("finally----" + escapeChar);

    if (config.getEscape() == null) {
        escapeEnabled = false;
    } else {
        escapeEnabled = true;
        escapeChar = config.getEscape();
        if (delim == escapeChar) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Delimiter cannot match the escape character");
        }
    }
    recordTerminator = config.getRecordTerminator();
    if (recordTerminator == null) {
        recordTerminator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    }
}

@Override
public void write(Object value) throws IOException {
    write((String[]) value);

}

public void write(String[] record) throws IOException {
    cmrdelimitor = cmrAppender + delim;

    logger.debug("&&&&& CRM Delimiter is : " + cmrdelimitor);
    if (escapeEnabled) {
        int pos = 0;
        for (String field : record) {
            if (pos++ > 0)
                out.write(cmrdelimitor);
            char[] cs = field.toCharArray();
            for (int i = 0, j = cs.length; i < j; i++) {
                if (cs[i] == delim || cs[i] == escapeChar) {
                    out.write(escapeChar);
                }
                out.write(cs[i]);
            }
        }
    } else {
        int pos = 0;
        for (String field : record) {
            if (pos++ > 0) {
                out.write(cmrdelimitor);

            }
            out.write(field);

        }
    }
    out.write(recordTerminator);

}

@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    out.close();

}

@Override
public void flush() throws IOException {
    out.flush();

}

}
```

The configuration file is -

```
    <record name="currencyExtract" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" class="com.barclays.paymentshub.ref.extract.dto.CurrencyExtract">
        <field name="ccyCode" />
        <field name="ccyGtslCutoffTime" />
        <field name="ccyGtslCutoffDays" />
        <field name="ccyBuyRate" />
        <field name="ccyBuyReferInd" />
        <field name="ccySellRate" />
        <field name="ccySellReferInd" />
        <field name="ccyReciprocalInd" />           
        <field name="ccySubUnitInd" />
        <field name="ccyToBeRounded" />
        <!-- <field name="ccyNumeric" /> -->
    </record>
</stream>
```

Answer (score 0):

- You need to define the parser on the mapping file (See below)
- Then create a StringDelimitedParserFactory and Override createWriter to return
  RecordWriter
- Finally you need RecordWriter implementation which should use the intended
  delimiter.

StringDelimitedParserFactory

```
@Override
public RecordWriter createWriter(Writer out) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    return new StringDelimitedWriter(out, strDelimiter);
}
public void setDelimiter(String delimiter) {
    this.delimiter= delimiter;
}
```

StringDelimitedWriter

```
public class StringDelimitedWriter implements RecordWriter {
private String delimeter = "\t";

public void write(String[] record) throws IOException {
    if (escapeEnabled) {
        int pos = 0;
        for (String field : record) {
            if (pos++ > 0)
                out.write(delimeter);

            char[] cs = field.toCharArray();
            for (int i = 0, j = cs.length; i < j; i++) {
                if (delimeter.equals(cs[i]) || cs[i] == escapeChar) {
                    out.write(escapeChar);
                }
                out.write(cs[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        int pos = 0;
        for (String field : record) {
            if (pos++ > 0) {
                out.write(delimeter);
            }
            out.write(field);
        }
    }

    out.write(recordTerminator);
}
```

mapping-file.xml

```
<parser class="xxx.xx.StringDelimitedParserFactory">
    <property name="delimiter" value="||" />
</parser>

<record name="currencyExtract" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" class="com.barclays.paymentshub.ref.extract.dto.CurrencyExtract">
    <field name="ccyCode" />
    <field name="ccyGtslCutoffTime" />
    <field name="ccyGtslCutoffDays" />
    <field name="ccyBuyRate" />
    <field name="ccyBuyReferInd" />
</record>
```